# Get mod_proxy to pass a custom header to backend

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, request-headers

I have a Python backend that is being reverse proxied by Apache/mod_proxy using fcgi (httpd 2.4 on rhel7).

I have a client that sets a custom header in the request, however mod_proxy does not appear to be sending that header on to the backend.

I know something similar exists for the host as ProxyPreserveHost - I would like to know how to do something similar for a custom header.

Can I do that with mod_proxy, or will I need to fall back on to mod_rewrite in some way?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It seems this line preserves the Header for reasons I don't quite understand:

```
SetEnvIf HTTP_MY_HEADER "(.*)" MY_HEADER=$0
```

The reason I don't understand this is that I am setting an Env var here, not a header -- are Env vars automatically turned into headers?

I though I might have to do this also, but was unnecessary:

```
RequestHeader set HTTP_MY_HEADER "${MY_HEADER}e"
```

I suppose this is an answer as "it works", although I would love to know why...